# Problem editing a text file in C ++, defining a dash, adding / removing spaces

Tags: c++

Here is the task:
[Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Ydd.png)

And if I dealt with the removal of extra spaces more or less, then I have obvious problems with adding a space after the punctuation mark and with a dash or hyphen (I just can’t even imagine how this can be implemented). I tried to define a dash through if ... else, but nothing came of it. Here is my code at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string DelSpaces(string s)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
    {
        if (s[j] == ' ')
        {
            while (s[j + 1] == ' ') s.erase(j + 1, 1);
        }
    }
    if (s[0] == ' ') s.erase(0, 1);
    if (s[s.length() - 1] == ' ') s.erase(s.length() - 1, 1);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    ifstream F("C:\\Folder\\Baseball.txt", ios::in);
    string a;

    while (getline(F, a))
    {

        a = DelSpaces(a);
        cout << " " << a << endl;

    }
    F.close();
    cin.get();
}
```

Here is the text file itself (or rather, what is written there):
[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVixc.png)

The result of the program:
[Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0HIF.png)

Using if ... else tried to write something like this:

```
if ('--')
    {
        cout << ' - ';
    }
    else if (' -' || '-' || '- ')
    {
        cout << ' - ';
    }
```

I really count on your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: '--' is not a single character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, a few basic things:

`'x'` is a character, a `char`. `' - '` is an error - it looks like three characters stuck together, but three characters stuck together does not fit in a `char`, so the compiler just chokes on it.

`"x"` is a string (specifically it is a `char[]`, also called a C-string - which is not the same as a `std::string`, though you can construct a `std::string` from a `char[]`) containing the characters `'x'` and `'\0'` (`'\0'` is the null character, which is normally used to terminate strings). `" - "` is a string containing the characters `' '`, `'-'`, `' '`, and `'\0'`

So, how do you go from there?

One way is to check characters one at a time:

```
if (s[j] == '-' && s[j+1] == '-')  // check for "--"
{
  s.replace(j, 2, " - ");
}
```

If you are feeling masochistic and want to hand-optimize this stuff, you can even cascade these checks:

```
if (s[j] == 'a')
{
    if (s[j + 1] == 'x')
    {
        // we found "ax"
    }
    if (s[j + 1] == 'y')
    {
        // we found "ay"
    }
}
```

But I would really not do this unless you are forced to it - it is a massive amount of fiddling with nested if's for a gain you probably won't notice. On the other hand, if you are having fun, then perhaps a school project is the place to play with it.

Oh, and in either of these approaches you should probably also have some checks to make sure you don't start poking outside your string; looking at `s[j+5]` when your string ended at `s[j+2]` is pretty bad.

Another way is to use the [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function in `std::string`:

```
std::string::size_type n;
n = s.find("--");
s.replace(n, 2, " - ");
```

Note that you can also give `find` a starting position, so that it does not keep going over the text you have already processed:

```
std::string::size_type n;
n = s.find("--");               // Find the first instance of "--"
                                // Find returns npos if there is no match
while (n != std::string::npos)  // Loop while there is a match
{
    s.replace(n, 2, " - ");     // Replace "--" with " - "
    n = s.find("--", n + 3);    // Find the next match, starting at the character after the " - " that we just added
}
```